# rename json payload fields from pino logger

Tags: nestjs

is it possible to edit the jsonpayload fields from the nestjs-pino logger?

I need to rename the msg field into message, if its possbile.

Thats how my log message looks now with the msg field:

```
{"context":true, "hostname":"localhost", "level":30, "msg":"Nest application successfully started", "pid":14, "time":1.641304507274E12}
```

best regards and thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can:

```
const logger = pino({ 
  ..., 
  messageKey: 'message', 
};
```

more details: https://github.com/pinojs/pino/blob/HEAD/docs/api.md#messagekey-string